# gridview inside listview layoutparams android

Tags: android, listview, gridview, layoutparams

use:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
final int type = getItemViewType(position);

if(position == 1){
    GridView gridView = new GridView(context);
    gridView.setNumColumns(3);
    AbsListView.LayoutParams params = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    gridView.setLayoutParams(params);
    ArrayAdapter<String>  adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.item, R.id.tvText, new String[]{"as","ah","ah","ah","ah","ah","ah","ah","ah","ah","ah","ah","ah","ah","ah","ah","ah","ah","ah","ah","ah","ah","ah"});
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
    return gridView;
}
```

but the gridview is not shown in full. Why?

screenshot:
[image]

and I should like this: 
[image]

[item.xml](http://pastebin.com/LwancVY1)

Comment: List inside List is not recommended.
Instead GridView I sugesst using a TableLayout

Comment: Why is there a new Adapter created inside the getView()-method of the adapter?

Comment: jimpanzer xml added
bofredo this test project. I know that is so wrong